# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, json, runtime-error

I'm trying to parse JSON object Value in this website.. Yet i get runtime error : Unable to start activity componentinfo: Illegal character in url..
This my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String TAG_ROWS = "row";
    private static final String TAG_ELEMENTS = "elements";
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE = "distance";
    private static final String TAG_VALUE = "value";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "destination_addresses";
    String data;
    HttpClient client; 
    double minDistance=0;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    String destination_addresses;
    JSONArray rows;
    JSONArray elements;
    String value;
    final static String URL= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            try {
                ClosestObject();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        finally {

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            result.setText(data);

    }



public void ClosestObject () throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
    String param= "origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=false";
    String encodedparams = URLEncoder.encode(param,"UTF-8");
    String FinalUrl= URL +encodedparams;
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(FinalUrl);

   HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    HttpEntity en = r.getEntity();
    data = EntityUtils.toString(en);
    jObj = new JSONObject(data);


        try {


            rows = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ROWS);
            elements = rows.getJSONArray(0);
            for (int i=0; i<elements.length();i++){
                 JSONObject obj = elements.getJSONObject(i);
                 JSONObject distance = obj.getJSONObject(TAG_DISTANCE);
                  value= distance.getString(TAG_VALUE);
                  double distanceValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                  if ( distanceValue < minDistance){
                      minDistance = distanceValue;
                  }
            }

         }  
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }



@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**This is the error :**
04-01 21:06:05.734: D/AndroidRuntime(1045): Shutting down VM
04-01 21:06:05.734: W/dalvikvm(1045): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.distance/com.example.distance.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 97: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=falsehttp://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=false
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 97: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=falsehttp://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=false
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.(HttpPost.java:79)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.example.distance.MainActivity$JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(MainActivity.java:68)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.example.distance.MainActivity.ClosestObject(MainActivity.java:115)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.example.distance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-01 21:06:05.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     ... 11 more

I can not thank you enough for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query

means you are not passing Querying String(parameters) with url in right format. use `URLEncoder.encode` for encoding special characters before appending to URL.

**Example:**

```
String str_url="http://www.xxxxxx.com?";
String str_parameters = "param123=abc|test&param=abc test";
String encodedparams = URLEncoder.encode(str_parameters,"UTF-8");

String str_finalurl=str_url+encodedparams;
```

Comment: but this is a correct link thou http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=false

Comment: @KarleeB : first use HttpGet instead of HttpPost because current request is get instead of post

Comment: @KarleeB : plz edit your post with latest code then i will try to help u more

Comment: @KarleeB : in current code im not able to see URLEncoder.encode ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add..let me do that.. wait

Comment: @KarleeB : ok use [this code](http://pastebin.com/7aYKu9hW) and let me known it's working on ur end or not

Comment: HOLY SMOKE MAN..You are a genius ...it shows something..doesnt crash..How can I attach screen shot?

Comment: @KarleeB : not showing showing it's showing JSON String just add your json parsing code in onPostExecute method

Comment: Well, i shows the site but empty, the values are empty.. the problem is i need the link ultimatly be http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false

Comment: it creates this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json and shos this content

Comment: @KarleeB : on my edit http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json link also not shwoing anything

Comment: yeaaa..it need the full link with origin and destination but when i put full link it shows error

Comment: Ay idea why? why not working with http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=burnaby|Victoria+BC|Surrey+BC&mode=driving&language=en-FR&sensor=false